# autoref, titleclass and titlesec -- display parent and child counter

Tags: hyperref, counters, titlesec, autoref

I want to implement a new titleclass for workpackages (WP) and a nested title subclass for subworkpackages. Both should work similar to `\section` and `\subsection`, i.e., the subworkpackage counter is reset when the workpackage counter is increased.

To achieve this I use the `\titleclass` command of the titlesec package, along with respective `\newcounter` commands. However, a problem is, that when I refer to the **sub**workpackages with autoref, then only the counter of the subworkpackage is displayed. However, I want the counter of the parent workpackage, followed by "." followed by the counter of the subworkpackage, as it is with sections and subsection.

For example, if `wp:sub2test` is the label for the second subworkpackage within the first parent workpackage, then `\autoref{wp:sub2test}` should display "WP 1.2". However, as you see in my MWE, it displays "WP 2". How can I fix this, i.e., how can I tell autoref to spit out the parent counter, followed by a dot, followed by the child counter?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\workpackage}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{workpackage}
\titleformat{\workpackage}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{WP \theworkpackage \quad -- \quad}
\titlespacing*{\workpackage}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\workpackageautorefname}{WP}

\titleclass{\subworkpackage}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{subworkpackage}
\titleformat{\subworkpackage}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{WP \theworkpackage.\thesubworkpackage \quad -- \quad}
\titlespacing*{\subworkpackage}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\subworkpackageautorefname}{WP}

\begin{document}

\workpackage{test}
\label{wp:test}
some wp
\subworkpackage{sub1test}
\label{wp:sub1test}
some subwp

\subworkpackage{sub2test}
\label{wp:sub2test}
some subwp

\section{Referring to WP with autoref}
\label{sec:sec}
This gives \autoref{wp:test} and \autoref{wp:sub1test} and \autoref{wp:sub2test}, but it should give WP 1 and WP 1.1 and WP 1.2.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

The `subworkpackage` is a 'child' level of `workpackage`, not of `\section`, therefore it must use `\workpackage` as 'parent', not `\section`, otherwise all counter information will be wrong and the reference labels as well!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\titleclass{\workpackage}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{workpackage}
\titleformat{\workpackage}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{WP \theworkpackage \quad -- \quad}
\titlespacing*{\workpackage}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\workpackageautorefname}{WP}

\titleclass{\subworkpackage}{straight}[\workpackage]
\newcounter{subworkpackage}
\renewcommand{\thesubworkpackage}{\theworkpackage.\arabic{subworkpackage}}
\titleformat{\subworkpackage}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{WP \thesubworkpackage \quad -- \quad}
\titlespacing*{\subworkpackage}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\subworkpackageautorefname}{WP}



\begin{document}

\workpackage{test}
\label{wp:test}
some wp
\subworkpackage{sub1test}
\label{wp:sub1test}
some subwp

\subworkpackage{sub2test}
\label{wp:sub2test}
some subwp

\section{Referring to WP with autoref}
\label{sec:sec}
This gives \autoref{wp:test} and \autoref{wp:sub1test} and \autoref{wp:sub2test}, but it should give WP 1 and WP 1.1 and WP 1.2.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ManfredEppe: Happy TeXing then! The usual policy to 'thank somebody' is to accept the answer ;-)